# Create a new account from the old one

Tags: account, clone

Morning all:

I have a client who has changed some data in his business. I need to create a new account with this new data (name, TAX id...) but keep all the data (contracts, files...) from the old account.

I also have to keep the old account to have visibility of the two accounts, so I can't directly edit the old account.

How can I make a duplicate account??? In the Salesforce documentation I only find "how to merge accounts", but not the step to duplicate accounts by changing some data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clone with Related on Account record: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.basics_clone_records.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral This should be an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @identigral I use this main. I create a botton in GUI for clone an account, but don't clone contacts, contracts or another file for this account.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use the `.clone()` method in Apex that is provided by the `SObject` class. The biggest consideration here is that you'll only clone the fields that you either query or explicitly set in code.

The code would look something like

```java
// First, we need to get the API names of all the fields
// The simplest approach is to just use the SObject Describe Information
List<String> fieldAPINames = new List<String>(Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().keySet());

Id targetAccountId = '<some account Id here>';
// Query your target Account
// Needs to use a query string and the Database.query() method if you want to avoid
//   typing out each and every field
// I prefer using String.format() to straight string concatenation, but either
//   approach will work
String acctQuery = String.format('SELECT {0} FROM Account WHERE Id = {1}',
    new List<Object>{
        // First item in the list gets put in the placeholder with the label 0
        String.join(fieldAPINames, ', '),
        // Second item in the list get put in the placeholder with the label 1
        '\'' + targetAccountId + '\''
    }
);

Account target = Database.query(acctQuery);

// The clone method takes 4 arguments, but they're all false by default and that
//   should be good enough for what you're trying to do
// The first argument being false means that the clone won't have the Id of the original
Account clonedAccount = target.clone();

insert clonedAccount;
```

This can be run via anonymous apex. It is untested.

About the only other advice to give here is to treat the clone as the "old Account" and have the original become the "new Account". That approach will save you the trouble of re-parenting all of the related records.

Comment: N.B. often, when using this approach, one needs to clear some fields that are application-specific, especially those set by automation

Answer (score 0):

As Derek mentioned, it's best to treat the clone as the old account, and then you simply update the original account's fields to become the new account.  You can just use the [Clone action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392237&language=en_US&type=1) on the Account page layout to create the clone.

You probably don't want Clone with Related Records because it could be confusing to have duplicate contracts, files etc for both the old account and the new account.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for: clone contracts, contacts, etc...
I try this solution, but this "clone", not clone Account files, contact, contracts....